# why don't we use three pivot quicksort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I was reading research paper [Multi-Pivot Quicksort: Theory and Experiments](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611973198.6) of S Kushagra where he claim with result that  three pivot quicksort works better than dual pivot sort then why don't we use them in lang libraries of java or c ?

Comment: yes,I am asking about library implementation.Modifed question

Comment: Because sorting algorithms in these languages have been implemented ages ago and this paper is comparatively new, and possibly very unknown amongst the implementers of said libraries...!? *"Why isn't..."* is virtually impossible to answer.

Comment: Well, for my own C library, I took the implementation from a different library in 2003, reworked it in 2005 for code quality, disabled a dodgy testcase in 2006 that threw BSD into an endless loop, did a patch for worst-case stack usage in 2009, and pretty much forgot about it because it was "good enough". Apparently SDL copied the implementation into their code base a couple of weeks ago. And in all that time, I have never actually *used* `qsort()`, so squeezing some more clock cycles out of its algorithm was not really a priority. I might, however, thanks for the link. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

> why don't we use them in lang libraries of java or c ?

The 3-pivot algorithm in  Multi-Pivot Quicksort: Theory and
Experiments of S Kushagra is 'academic-strength'; i.e. an integer
array with as input a permutation of [1-N].

A robust 3-pivot version for referenced items (records/ objects) in C is
available at: 
     https://github.com/ddccc/sixsort
A pdf paper about it is at:
     https://github.com/ddccc/MultiPivotParallelQuicksort

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While the provided links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231